# MySQL determine number of users in system hourly query

Tags: mysql, sql, audit, self-join

I have an application writing to MySQL with the below audit table format. I need to determine the current number of users logged in to the system at any given time during the day.
I have tried this with various self joins, sub queries, timediff, and even converting to unixtime plus some simple math, however I am unable to come up with a solution that is acceptable. 
Any pointers or assistance is appreciated greatly.

audit_table

```
user | action | time
-----|--------|------
  1  | login  | 2013-07-02 00:37:00
  2  | login  | 2013-07-02 00:38:00
  1  | logout | 2013-07-02 00:39:30
  3  | login  | 2013-07-02 00:40:00
  2  | logout | 2013-07-02 02:30:00
```

Needed format: hour of 24 hour day | number of users logged in during that hour

Example (Note that user 3 has not logged out yet, thus still showing active in the count in hour 3)

```
hour | usersloggedin
-----|---------------
  0  |  3
  1  |  2
  2  |  2
  3  |  1
```

Comment: More sample data please and **always** post what you've tried. When we play around with your sample data, the result currently would be that every user would fall into the hour = 0 row. I assume it can be possible that a user has multiple logins and logouts? Do you determine in any way which login belongs to which logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before all you need to create a table for example called hours_table with number from 00 to 23:

```
CREATE TABLE `hours_table` (`hour` char(2) DEFAULT NULL); 

hour
----
00
01
02
03
04
..
```

After you execute this query:

```
SELECT  hour, (count(DISTINCT(li.user)) - count(DISTINCT(lo.user))) AS usersloggedin  FROM hours_table    
LEFT JOIN audit_table AS li ON  DATE_FORMAT(li.time, '%Y%m%d%H')<=CONCAT('20130702',hour)  AND DATE_FORMAT(li.time, '%Y%m%d')='20130702' AND li.action='login'
LEFT JOIN audit_table AS lo ON  DATE_FORMAT(lo.time, '%Y%m%d%H')<CONCAT('20130702',hour)  AND DATE_FORMAT(lo.time, '%Y%m%d')='20130702' AND lo.action='logout' 
GROUP BY hour
```

In place of 20130702 you put an other day in format yyyymmdd remove DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y%m%d')='20130702' if you consider user logged yesterday active today.

Comment: I do get a proper display of hour|usersloggedin now, but the count for users logged in is always 0. Adding the same 2 count statements you used to the select for debug purposes shows me that they both always =1, meaning I always get 1-1=0 in the results.

Comment: I have tested and this method work fine. Please add your sql syntax.

Comment: Exact same syntax as you posted above. Perhaps my issue is with the hour_table, I created and inserted values, but my 0* values are only showing as 1,2,3,4 instead of 00,01,02,03. That should still allow anything hour=10 or higher to work though. I used this to insert, I assume its wrong -- insert into hours_table (hour) values (00)

Comment: field type is it char or varchar?

Comment: char(2) as you stated above. AND it works! Sorry about that, any other day I try works perfect, except the one in the example, which has login/logout info... Not sure whats up, maybe an issue with my client or brain, but all other days work perfectly.